# amsmath: error using subequation environment "Missing \endgroup inserted \end{align}"

Tags: amsmath

Here's my minimal problem-causing example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            a &= b + c\\
            a' &= b' + c'\\
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Here's the log output:

```
line 14: Missing \endgroup inserted \end{align}
line 14: Missing \endgroup inserted \end{align}
line 14: Missing } inserted \end{align}
line 14: \begin{document} ended by \end{align}. \end{align}
line 14: Missing $ inserted \end{align}
line 14: Display math should end with $$ \end{align}
line 14: Extra \endgroup \end{align}
line 15: \begin{document} ended by \end{subequations}. \end{subequations}
line 15: Extra \endgroup \end{subequations}
line 17: Too many }'s \end{document}
```

What is the issue?

Comment: You can't use display environments in `standalone` unless you're using the `varwidth` option.

Comment: @egreg This fixes my problem. Would you like to write up a super short answer I could accept?

Comment: not relevant to the error message, but you really shouldn't end an `align` structure with a double backslash -- it adds an unwanted blank line following the display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for letting me know that! I have made it a habit not to leave empty lines in align environments now.